# Spring Integration null originalMessage in ErrorMessage

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We are really confused with error handling in Spring Integration. We are using Boot 2.0.2 and Kotlin.

Within a `@Transformer` we throw an Exception `X`.

Also, within a Java DSL flow definition, we throw the same exception `X`

Channels

```
@Bean(TO_BE_PROCESSED_CHANNEL)
fun toBeProcessed() = PublishSubscribeChannel(defaultExecutor())
```

Flow

```
@Configuration
class VideoDescriptorPersistSubflow(
    val videoRepository: JdbcVideoRepository,
    val ingestRecordRepository: CustomIngestRecordRepository
) {

@Bean
fun videoDescriptorPersistFlow(
        toBeProcessed: MessageChannel,
        processedVideos: MessageChannel
) =
        IntegrationFlows.from(toBeProcessed)
                .filter { message: Message<*> -> message.ingestRecordId() != null }
                .handle { videoDescriptor: VideoDescriptor, _ -> validateVideoDescriptor(videoDescriptor) }
                .handle { videoDescriptor: VideoDescriptor, _ -> videoRepository.persist(videoDescriptor) }
                .channel(processedVideos)
                .get()

fun validateVideoDescriptor(videoDescriptor: VideoDescriptor): VideoDescriptor {
    val errors = VideoDescriptorValidator().validate(videoDescriptor)
    if (errors.isNotEmpty()) {
        throw VideoMetadataValidationException(errors)
    }

    return videoDescriptor
}
```

Later in the `errorChannel` we filter out `X` and do some stuff. At that point **we need the failed message**.

For the exception thrown by the `@Transformer` the originalMessage is there.

For the one thrown from the java DSL subflow, the originalMessage is null.

We did some digging and realised, the former is wrapped in `MessagingExceptionWrapper` whereas the later is wrapped in a `MessageHandlingException` which does not contain a reference to the original message.

Could someone please help us understand under what circumstances Spring Integration wraps using what exceptions? Docs do not say much here, or we couldn't find anything relevant.

**UPDATE: CHANGING FROM PUBSUB TO QUEUE CHANNEL MAKES IT WORK...**

**UPDATE 2: Following Gary's advide we are now using payload.failed message, which works just fine. There is something dodgy though with originalMessage in ErrorMessage.**

Comment: You need to show the configuration in both cases and what precedes the integration flow DSL.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell I was really hoping you were around.

Changing from aChannel from a PubSub with an executor to a Queue makes it work...

Let me add more config here (although, that's pretty much it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`payload.failedMessage` is the message at the time of failure. `ErrorMessage.originalMessage` is the message at the start of the flow. It is not populated in all cases.

Comment: But org.springframework.messaging.support.ErrorMessage only contains originalMessage. 

We cast to that after picking up the message from the errorQueue...

Comment: Generally the `ErrorMessage.payload.failedMessage` is most relevant. `ErrorMessage.originalMessage` (the message where the exception is caught) is added in many cases, when it is available. If you show your configuration, we can determine if it's a bug or not.